# Electrical Potential Energy and Electric Force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, potential, potential-energy

Under certain circumstances, potassium ions $(K+)$ move across the $8.0 nm$ thick cell membrane from the inside to the outside. The potential inside the cell is $−70 mV$ and the potential outside is $0mV$.

a. What is the change in the electrical potential energy of the
    potassium ions as they move across the membrane? Does their potential energy increase or decrease as they move from the inside to    the outside?

b. What electrical force (magnitude and direction) is exerted on the
    potassium ions when they are inside the potassium channel that spans
    the cell membrane, assuming that it behaves electrically like water
    (flowing freely like water)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Change in potential energy = $(V_f - V_i)q = 70e$ mJ where $e$ is the charge on one proton. Therefore, potential energy increases.

b) The electric field inside the membrane points towards the inside. Since $\vec{E} = -\frac{dV}{dx}$, assuming the electric field to be uniform, we obtain $|\vec{E}| = 70$ mV/$8$ nm $= 8.75 \times 10^6$ V/m.

Since work is done on the positive ion against the elctric field, it gains potential energy.